Novel series based in Utah about mandatory microchips and MMA-style fighting
I am looking for the name of the book series where the government is requiring microchips and based in Utah.  I remember the talked about something like MMA fighting but more violent.
The microchip was for identification and implanted in arm. I just remember their was a group of people that didn't want. I believe this was from the 2000 to 2010 and I think there was at least 2 books in the series. The fighting was done as entertainment but I seem to remember it was also done as a punishment.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  How many books were there?  What did the microchips do?  Where were they installed?  What was the purpose of the fighting?  Who fought?

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

So the government is based in Utah (as opposed to Washington D.C.)? Or that the action of the novel was in Utah?
